# What is task polling?

Tags: task, polling, netflix-conductor

I am going through Netflix Conductor documentation. It keeps using task polling and loop polling but I can't seem to get my head around it. Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Conductor server has a queue, when a task is scheduled, it mean conductor put a record into that queue (image like insert into queue_message values ...) ~ Image the manager creating a issue on Jira on some project board

Conductor worker/client will keep polling the server, using REST that will result in querying the above queue_message for a specific taskType (depend on the worker) ~ Image the developer keeps checking the board for thing to do and pick up the thing to work on once he sees it.